# Use nmap scan specific ports to see which IP addresses are running any of those

Tags: connection, nmap, tcp-ip

I have a question to write a script using nmap to look at TCP ports across the entire network to identify which IP addresses are running any of those services.

Sorry my english is not good.

Comment: Read `man nmap`. That kind of thing is what `nmap` was designed for. Warning: Depending on what you mean by "across the entire network", you could be on the edge of illegal behaviour. Ensure the the network manager is aware, and approves. A Port Scan is often a precursor to an attack. Don't trigger a response - get approval first.

Comment: Which services are you referring to ?

Comment: it's just a normal scan, because I'm new to nmap and I heard it can do lot of things, so I just want to give it a try. *waltinator

Comment: tcp ports 53 and 123 services =) *George

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is this:

```
nmap -p 53,123 192.168.0.0/24
```

- `-p`  specifies list of comma-separated ports.
- `192.168.0.0/24` tells to scan local network in CIDR notation. Please note that if you are scanning a local network, you need to know what type it is; for example `/24` means there are 2^(32-24) - 1 = 255 possible host addresses ( and if you exclude  router, broadcast, and network ID there are 3 less addresses ). Use `ip addr -o` to find on what network you are on.

Of course, you can use other options in combination with this to perform various types of scans.